# MarkLogic node.js Client API - Query by element value with XML namespace

Tags: node.js, marklogic

Say I have a collection with records structured like so:

```
<m:m xmlns:m="http://www.m.com/">
    <m:data>
        <z:term xmlns:z="http://z.come/schema/index.html#">
            <z:name>abcd</z:name>
            <z:id>123456789</z:id>
......
```

And then I want to select records where z:id = whatever or z:name = whatever. How can I do this with queryBuilder?

I've been able to successfully make such queries when there is no namespace. With the namespaces it doesn't seem to work the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the target element using [QueryBuilder.element()](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#element). The documentation for element() says there are three ways to specify the element's QName:

> A name without a namespace can be expressed as a string. A namespaced name can be expressed as a two-item array with uri and name strings or as an object returned by the [queryBuilder#qname](http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#qname) function.

```
var ml = require('marklogic');
var conn = require('./config.js').connection;
var db = ml.createDatabaseClient(conn);
var qb = ml.queryBuilder;

db.documents.query(
  qb.where(
    qb.value(qb.element(['http://z.come/schema/index.html#', 'id']), '123456789')
  )
).result()
.then(function(docs) {
  console.log('This search found: ' + JSON.stringify(docs[0]));
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('something went wrong: ' + error);
});
```

Comment: Or, instead of the array, you can use the qb.qname() function:

http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/queryBuilder.html#qname